# Alamofire - detect internet connection

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

#### How to detect connection to internet?

---

I have a viewController that displays data fetched from a server. It is presented modally.

I display a message asking for an internet connection if a user is not connected to the internet. Otherwise, I show the data.

When a user connects to the internet without leaving the app, how to detect it? I assume it is possible to do it in **Alamofire**.

I have used the following code in **viewDidLoad** and **viewWillAppear**, but the listener is not called - If I connect & disconnect to WIFI, **startListening** is not called.

```
    let network = NetworkReachabilityManager()
    network!.startListening { status in
        if status == .reachable(.cellular) || status == .reachable(.ethernetOrWiFi) {
            self.fetchProducts()
        } else {
            self.noInternetConnnection()
        }
    }
```

---

*FYI, you can unable both WIFI and Mobile Data in control center.*

Comment: What do you mean with "it does not work", does the listener is called when network status change? Otherwise the code block should work.

Comment: @omerfarukozturk You are right. I updated my questions.

Comment: You should not be checking for connectivity *before* making a network request. You should make the request and properly handle any failures instead.

Comment: @JonShier I just want to say thank you very much. I do what you have suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're declaring `network` inside a function it's probably being deallocated as soon as the scope ends.

Make sure you store it in an instance variable.